# [HttpURLConnection]How to send a post request with form-data

Tags: java

I am faced with a problem regarding to the `HttpURLConnection`. I want to send a POST request with 2 keys in the body (form-data).

```
URL obj = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("POST");

// add header
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
con.setRequestProperty("cookie", cookies);

con.setDoInput(true);
con.setDoOutput(true);
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
wr.flush();
wr.close();
```

How do I add the body (form-data)?

For example, I would to add 2 keys, name: "abc" and password: "abc": [Form-Data Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3jFE.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Content-Disposition: form-data;` followed by form-data parameters.

```
String name = "abc";
String password = "abc";
String crlf = "\r\n";
wr.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + name + "\"; password=\"" + password + "\""+ crlf);
```